# building website graphics with GWT

Tags: user-interface, graphics, gwt

i am building a site with GWT. i have finished all the logics and now i need to work on the graphics/UI.

i am just begining my way at web site and i have 2 questions:

1) how can i make my web site look good in every resolution?

2) in most of the places i have read that the UI components (background/buttons..) is always in a table. but i dont really understand why, since in GWT has containers for the alignment.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

For the second question, GWT uses tables because it has to translate the code into HTML and Javascript.  Sure, they have containers, but they didn't implement those containers in Javascript, they just bung everything into tables.  That's bad, because you end up with tables within tables within tables.  It's good, however, because it means you can do some cool stuff with CSS to style those tables.

Answer (score 0):

look at CSS sites for good multi-resolution (I'm assuming you mean screen/window sizes, really) tips, but in general avoid sizing text in pixels, go for ex or em, say, or pt. For very small screens (ie mobile devices), you may need to re-arrange the layout to make it easier to use, since a simple html re-flow, might not do the trick. Speaking of flow, a FlowPanel will handle different screen sizes better than a HorizontalPanel.